# Why does sorting and grouping in the proc report not work as I expect

Tags: sas, proc-report

I'm trying to sort my data by SUBJID DATE and group all other variables if they have the same value. But as I see values are sorting inside DATETIME groups and also other vars are grouping only insode DATETIME groups. Why it happens?

```
 column SUBJID DATE SUBJID_FMT DATETIME PARAM_FMT;

  define SUBJID/order order=internal noprint;
  define DATE/order=internal noprint;
  define SUBJID_FMT/order order=data"Subject ID" style(column)=[width=8%]; 
  define DATETIME/order order=data "Treatment:@Date/Time" style(column)=[width=14%]; 
  define PARAM_FMT/order order=data "Parameter" style(column)=[width=10%];
```

Comment: For your DATE column, you don't have it defined as ORDER. Can you expand your example to show and example dataset (5-10 records created by a data step with the CARDS statement), and the full PROC REPORT step using that sample data?  You mention grouping but you don't have any columns defined as GROUP.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe part of the problem is you didn't define the DATE column as order.

```
column SUBJID DATE SUBJID_FMT DATETIME PARAM_FMT;
define SUBJID/order order=internal noprint;
define DATE/order order=internal noprint; /*added ORDER here*/
define SUBJID_FMT/order order=data "Subject ID" style(column)=[width=8%]; 
define DATETIME/order order=data "Treatment:@Date/Time" style(column)=[width=14%]; 
define PARAM_FMT/order order=data "Parameter" style(column)=[width=10%];
```